# Why Yell "Geronimo" When Jumping From A Plane?

Tags: etymology

Can anyone explain the origin of the practice of yelling "Geronimo" when parachuting from a plane?

Comment: Have you tried to look this up yourself?

Comment: The always-reliable ;) [Wikipedia has this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geronimo_(exclamation)).

Comment: See the FAQ under ["Why are some questions closed?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#close) - general reference.

Comment: The question made me curious to know the answer, but sadly it's off-topic, and general reference to boot.

Comment: Feel free to close the question; I'd close it myself but apparently I don't have sufficient rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**This**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geronimo#In_popular_culture) wikipedia article says:

> Thanks to a 1939 movie about Geronimo, US paratroopers traditionally shout "Geronimo" to show they have no fear of jumping out of an airplane.